# How to list most viewed nodes using Statistics module?

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

How to list most viewed nodes using Statistics module in Drupal 6?

I'm looking for the PHP code to use in a custom theme.

Comment: You're probably better off using Views, with sorting based on number of hits. Content shouldn't usually be hard-coded into a theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have enabled this feature in admin panel before using the following code:

```
$number_of_hot = '10';
$hot_result = db_query_range("SELECT nid FROM {node_counter} ORDER BY totalcount DESC", array(), 0, $number_of_hot);
while ($hotid = db_result($hot_result)) {
$hot = node_load($hotid);
print $hot->title;
}
```